# Can I download an NPM package without the npm tool?

Tags: npm

I want to download https://npmjs.org/package/ripple-lib for inspection.  Most other systems I have dealt with provide a download link as well as the `command install package` syntax.  The npm site does not seem to provide such a download link.  Does anyone know another way?

Answer (score -1):

Download it from the github repository, which is linked on the page.

Comment: The github repo on that page is nonfunctional.  I just want the tarball.